# ReactJS - my slider'divs with background-images doesn t render the images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider

- here my model: https://codepen.io/joondoe/pen/oRzQVX
- here my trial:
  https://codesandbox.io/s/woj96pn59l

***I would reproduce the model background-image's slider with ReactJS.***

I m trying to render the image in my reactJS slider like the model, but it doesn t work, my background image show nothing and appear to be tiny bar of markup when I put content in the Slide component like `<div> content </div>`.

Here my react snippet:

```
const Slide = ({ slideRef, image, i }) => {
  console.log("image: ", image);
  const style = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: "50% 60%"
  };
  return <div ref={slideRef} className={style.slide_item} style={style} />;
};

       <div className={style.slide_container} style={styleContainer}>
              {this.state.imageStock.map((image, index) => {
                console.log("image in map: ", image);
                return (
                  <Slide
                    i={index}
                    slideRef={this.slide}
                    key={index}
                    image={image}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
```

here my CSS snippet:

```
   /* style injection in React component => true */

    .slide_metacontainer {
      position: relative;
      width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 500px;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      background: pink;
    }

    .slide_container {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: yellow;
      display: flex;
    }

    .slide_item {
      display: inline-block;
      min-height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
      background: blue;
    }
```

How make my slider works? 
Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: you  must add width: 100% to the style in slider

Comment: In react you pass inline css like this <div style = { {   width : 100 }} />  so which is equivalent to style = {width : 100 } and then you pass style inside <div style = {style }

Comment: thanks, with the former configuration I have transmuted the property to minHeight and minWidth and it works fine! But Im still wondering why I have to add this to the style instead of the CSS ? It is weird in some way

Comment: You can check this out https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822